# Kiselev's Geometry Problem 51

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am going through Kiselev's Geometry, Book I.
I am having trouble with problem 51.
The problem states:

> Give an example that disproves the proposition: "If the bisectors of two angles with a common vertex are perpendicular, then the angles are supplementary." Is the converse proposition true?

His definition of a supplementary angle goes as follows:

> Two angles [...] are called supplementary **if they have one common side**, and their **remaining two sides form continuations** of each other. [...] **the sum** of two supplementary angles **is 180°**.

But I cannot see how to disprove that proposition using his definition. Is it something lost in translation or is it something that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this picture provide some help?
[image]

Comment: Yes, a lot, actually. I take that the converse proposition would then be "If two angles with a common vertex are supplementary, then the bisectors are perpendicular." and would be true?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Angles can share a vertex without sharing a side.